# Need to get the pie chart with % values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, mschart, dynamic-binding

My ASPX part

```
<div runat="server" id="divMain">
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie">
            <Points>

                //I want this part to come from code-behind

                //<asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="1 Star"  YValues="100" />
                //<asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="2 Star" YValues="123" />
                //<asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="3 Star" YValues="155" />
                //<asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="4 Star" YValues="245" />

            </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">

            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Title="Test abc" />
        </Legends>
    </asp:Chart>
  </div>
```

My code-behind follows down:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] yValues = { 10, 27.5, 7, 12, 45.5 };
    string[] xNames = { "Mike", "John", "William", "George", "Alex" };

    Series series1 = new  Series("pie");
    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    series1.BorderWidth = 3;
    series1.ShadowOffset = 2;
    Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
    divMain.Controls.Add(Chart1);
}
```

But I am getting the following exception: "The DataSourceID of `Chart1` must be the ID of a control of type `IDataSource`.  A control with ID `SqlDataSource1` could not be found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` element from the `Chart` in your aspx page, it probably does not exist, and you don't need it as you try to fill the data to the chart programatically.

Comment: yes its working but the things i want to bind it in percentage like 20%, 45% like that instead of 20, 45.24 etc... could be helpful if you can. Thanks

Comment: You need to format the labels. Here's an article that might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/11/microsoft-chart-control-how-to-using-keywords.aspx